# Open generated PDF in new tab / window in perl

Tags: perl, pdf

Please help. I want to open generated PDF in new window / Tab in perl.

User needs to fill the form  like First Name,Last Name, Email in web page. The form contents will be filled in PDF using PDF generator. The PDF will be generate dynamically.

In my case,

There is no issue with PDF generation. The generated PDF opens in the same window.  This should be open in new tab/ window.

I have tried with "_blank" in form level. The form have certain validations. So it's opening 
in new tab when the form have validation errors.

The below the content type which i have used in the pdf page.

**content_type : application/pdf 

Content-Disposition : inline**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `target` attribute of a HTML `<form>` element, the page resulting from the form submission will always displayed using that target. Having a form which either returns a HTML page on invalid input or a PDF is generally a bad idea.

IMO the following is a better solution also from a usability standpoint:

1. Don't set a `target` on your form.
2. If the form is submitted successfully, return a new HTML page in the same window.
3. Create a link or a form with hidden inputs on that page that contain the parameters entered before.
4. Name the link something like "Open PDF".
5. Point the link to your script which actually creates the PDF.
6. Make the link open in a new window.

Alternatively, you could implement a JavaScript-based solution, possibly using AJAX.